# How to write a custom serializer for Java 8 LocalDateTime

Tags: java, json, scala, scala-2.11, lift-json

I have a class named `Child1` which I want to convert into JSON using Lift Json. Everything is working fine i was using `joda date time` but now i want to use Java 8 `LocalDateTime` but i am unable to write custom serializer for this here is my code

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import net.liftweb.json.Serialization.{ read, write }
import net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
import net.liftweb.json.Serializer
import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST._
import net.liftweb.json.Formats
import net.liftweb.json.TypeInfo
import net.liftweb.json.MappingException

class Child1Serializer extends Serializer[Child1] {
  private val IntervalClass = classOf[Child1]

  def deserialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[(TypeInfo, JValue), Child1] = {
    case (TypeInfo(IntervalClass, _), json) => json match {
      case JObject(
        JField("str", JString(str)) :: JField("Num", JInt(num)) :: 
        JField("MyList", JArray(mylist)) :: (JField("myDate", JInt(mydate)) :: 
        JField("number", JInt(number)) ::Nil)
      ) => {
        val c = Child1(
          str, num.intValue(), mylist.map(_.values.toString.toInt), new DateTime(mydate.longValue)
        )
        c.number = number.intValue()
        c
      }
      case x => throw new MappingException("Can't convert " + x + " to Interval")
    }
  }

  def serialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[Any, JValue] = {
    case x: Child1 => 
      JObject(
        JField("str", JString(x.str)) :: JField("Num", JInt(x.Num)) ::
        JField("MyList", JArray(x.MyList.map(JInt(_)))) :: 
        JField("myDate", JInt(BigInt(x.myDate.getMillis))) :: 
        JField("number", JInt(x.number)) :: Nil
      )
  }
}

Object Test extends App {
  case class Child1(var str:String, var Num:Int, MyList:List[Int], myDate:DateTime) {
    var number: Int=555
  }
  val c = Child1("Mary", 5, List(1, 2), DateTime.now())
  c.number = 1
  println("number" + c.number)
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new Child1Serializer
  val ser = write(c)
  println("Child class converted to string" + ser) 

  var obj = read[Child1](ser)
  println("object of Child is "+  obj)
  println("str" + obj.str)
  println("Num" + obj.Num)
  println("MyList" + obj.MyList)
  println("myDate" + obj.myDate)
  println("number" + obj.number)
}
```

now i want to use Java 8 `LocalDateTime` like this

```
case class Child1(var str: String, var Num: Int, MyList: List[Int], val myDate: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()) {
  var number: Int=555
}
```

what modification do i need to make in my custom serializer class `Child1Serializer` i tried to do it but i was unable to do it please help me

Answer (score 1):

In the serializer, serialize the date like this:

```
def serialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[Any, JValue] = {
case x: Child1 => 
  JObject(
    JField("str", JString(x.str)) :: JField("Num", JInt(x.Num)) ::
    JField("MyList", JArray(x.MyList.map(JInt(_)))) :: 
    JField("myDate", JString(x.myDate.toString)) :: 
    JField("number", JInt(x.number)) :: Nil
  )
```

}

In the deserializer,

```
def deserialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[(TypeInfo, JValue), Child1] = {
case (TypeInfo(IntervalClass, _), json) => json match {
  case JObject(
    JField("str", JString(str)) :: JField("Num", JInt(num)) :: 
    JField("MyList", JArray(mylist)) :: (JField("myDate", JString(mydate)) :: 
    JField("number", JInt(number)) ::Nil)
  ) => {
    val c = Child1(
      str, num.intValue(), mylist.map(_.values.toString.toInt), LocalDateTime.parse(myDate)
    )
    c.number = number.intValue()
    c
  }
  case x => throw new MappingException("Can't convert " + x + " to Interval")
 }
}
```

The LocalDateTime object writes to an ISO format using `toString` and the `parse` factory method should be able to reconstruct the object from such a string.

Comment: Child class converted to string{"str":"Mary","Num":5,"MyList":[1,2],"myDate":"2015-07-28T17:09:31.512","number":1}
[error] (run-main-1) net.liftweb.json.MappingException: unknown error
net.liftweb.json.MappingException: unknown error
    at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:46)
    at net.liftweb.json.JsonAST$JValue.extract(JsonAST.scala:312)
    at net.liftweb.json.Serialization$.read(Serialization.scala:58)
    at MessageTest$.delayedEndpoint$MessageTest$1(MessageTest.scala:58)
    at MessageTest$delayedInit$body.apply(MessageTest.scala:15)

Answer (score 1):

You can define the **LocalDateTime** serializer like this.

```
class LocalDateTimeSerializer extends Serializer[LocalDateTime] {
  private val LocalDateTimeClass = classOf[LocalDateTime]

  def deserialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[(TypeInfo, JValue), LocalDateTime] = {
    case (TypeInfo(LocalDateTimeClass, _), json) => json match {
      case JString(dt) =>  LocalDateTime.parse(dt)
      case x => throw new MappingException("Can't convert " + x + " to LocalDateTime")
    }
  }

  def serialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[Any, JValue] = {
    case x: LocalDateTime => JString(x.toString)
  }
}
```

Also define your formats like this

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new LocalDateTimeSerializer + new FieldSerializer[Child1]
```

Please note the usage of **FieldSerializer** to serialize the non-constructor filed, number

Comment: Child class converted to string{"number":1,"str":"Mary","Num":5,"MyList":[1,2],"myDate":"2015-07-28T16:45:44.030"}
[error] (run-main-2) net.liftweb.json.MappingException: unknown error
net.liftweb.json.MappingException: unknown error
    at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:46)
    at net.liftweb.json.JsonAST$JValue.extract(JsonAST.scala:312)
    at net.liftweb.json.Serialization$.read(Serialization.scala:58)
    at MessageTest$.delayedEndpoint$MessageTest$1(MessageTest.scala:42)
    )

Comment: Looks like an issue with paranamer library used by lift-json - https://github.com/paul-hammant/paranamer/issues/17